# how to detect keyboard event on phonejs

Tags: devexpress, phonejs

I been building apk for android device,

now I want to detect, when the user press enter key or search key on keyboard

also I interesting for the other devices like IOS and WinPhone .

If you have some example, 
I appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

here is some solution for my owned question.

you can try with JQuery solution:

```
jQuery( document ).on( "keypress", "#IdSender", function(evt){
     var keycode = evt.keyCode || evt.which;
     alert("KeyCode: " + keycode);
});
```